# Utility Maximisation Subject to Income and Time Constraints

Tags: reference-request, utility, consumer-theory

The consumption of economic goods often takes time. Consider, for example:

- Transport services, eg flights, rail journeys;
- Leisure goods, eg watching a film, visiting a park.

I would like to explore models of consumer or household behaviour in which utility in a period is maximised subject to both income and time constraints.

From a Google search, two important (but rather old) papers on this topic appear to be:

- [Becker, G S (1965) *A Theory of the Allocation of Time*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/215665892_A_Theory_of_Allocation_of_Time)
- [De Serpa, A C (1971) *A Theory of the Economics of Time*](https://econpapers.repec.org/article/ecjeconjl/v_3a81_3ay_3a1971_3ai_3a324_3ap_3a828-46.htm)

What are other (and more recent) key papers on this topic?

**Addendum 31 May 2018**

To give a simple example, suppose there are just two goods $X_1,X_2$ and utility $U$ is given by:

$$U = X_1^{0.5}X_2^{0.5}$$

Suppose further that the respective prices and time requirements are for $X_1 (1,2)$ and for $X_2 (2,1)$.  Thus the income and time constraints are:

$$X_1 + 2X_2 \leq I$$

$$2X_1 + X_2 \leq T$$

where $I$ is income and $T$ is available time. If $T$ is much larger than $I$ (low-income person), then the income constraint will be binding, and the time constraint will be slack, and vice versa if $I$ is much larger than $T$ (high-income person). Over an intermediate range, including $T = I$, both constraints will be binding. These different scenarios have different implications for the effect of a marginal change in price.  Perhaps time preference is relevant here but I can't immediately see how.

**Addendum 23 July 2018**

[This book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Consumption-Takes-Time-Implications-Schumpeter-ebook/dp/B000OI0R3I/ref=sr_1_10?ie=UTF8&qid=1532263760&sr=8-10&keywords=ian%20steedman&tag=enlighteconom-21) by Ian Steedman, reviewed [here](http://www.enlightenmenteconomics.com/blog/index.php/2018/07/taking-time-seriously-in-economics/) by Diane Coyle, looks relevant.

Comment: Relevant: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/19569/does-consumer-theory-assume-that-utility-functions-are-consistent-overtime

Answer (score 1):

Despite its funny title and although it is quite old you may find this paper interesting:

[The economics of the afterlife](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/abs/10.1086/260860&ved=2ahUKEwjS_9TAoa7bAhUOzqQKHbmGAogQFjAAegQICRAB&usg=AOvVaw23LctmgSAzihTpKed4mu1l) by Scott Gordon in the JPE. His argument is basically that in the presence of an infinite amount of time there would still be a rate of time preference.

A follow-up paper disproving Gordon's claim was written by Amegashie, but I haven't checked that one in detail. You can find that  [here](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.uoguelph.ca/~jamegash/Economics_000.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjS_9TAoa7bAhUOzqQKHbmGAogQFjADegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw33oDInjjTKsC6-RXRXNW_o).

Nb credit where credit is due: I would probably never have read the first paper without Yoram Bauman's presentation "Hyperinflation in hell"

Comment: Interesting (and unusually concise) papers.  But I can't see a direct relevance to my question, except perhaps to underline that time constraints are most relevant to utility maximisation _within a defined time period_, and more problematic over a lifetime of unknown duration or hypothetically over infinite time.

Comment: @AdamBailey I thought you might be interested to see what happens if one relaxes the time constraint. Moreover Gordon's paper partly hinges on the fact that one cannot do things *at the same time*  that is, order may matter, which seemed to be  part of your motivation as well. But I'll admit that the relevance is not as direct as you might like