# Influence on the consumption of $Y$ when the price of $X$ falls

Tags: microeconomics, consumer-theory, choice-theory

Consider the utility function $u(x,y)$ and two budget constraints $B_1: px + qy = 1$ and $B_2 : p_1x + qy = 1$ where $p_1 < p$. If $(x^*, y^*)$ and $(x_1^*, y_1^*)$  maximize $u$ subject to $B_1$ and $B_2$ respectively, will it mean that $y_1^* \leq y^*$?

When the price of good $X$ falls, it is evident that $X$ will be consumed more and so $x_1^* > x^*$. I was wondering how $y^*$ is influenced and it seems $y_1^* \leq y^*$ but I am not sure. Any help will be appreciated. ^_^

Assume [rationality](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/17853) and convexity.

Comment: "*it is evident that $X$ will be consumed more*" While evident, the statement is not true, see Giffen-goods.

Comment: What happens to the consumed quantity of $Y$ when the price of $X$ increases depends on their relationship, see substitutes vs. complements.

Comment: @Giskard If this helps, I drew it. The red point belongs to the new budget constraint and its $y$ coordinate is more than that of the blue point. https://share.sketchpad.app/22/ab5-b2b4-924de0.png I am asking if this is possible.

Comment: This is indeed *possible*, in fact this is what happens if the utility function is e.g., $U(x,y) = \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}$.

Comment: @Giskard I read about perfect complements. Apart from $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}$, I think perfect complements $\min(x,y)$ will also satisfy it. Are complements Gidden goods then?